# Cocoa pod not being installed or used on Apple watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I'm using lockbox for key chain management in my iOS app. I'm building a watch version. 
On the actual watch it seems like the the lockbox pod isn't actually present even though it is being linked and there are no compile or linking errors.
Here's why i think this is so:

1. I have a wrapper on lockbox (credential)
2. I changed 'getUserName'  in credential to return "bob"
3. I changed the lockbox method to return "joe"

When i run with option (1) user name is blank. With option (2) it is always "bob". However with option (3) it is only "joe" in the app and blank in the watch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think keychain wrapper will work on apple watch at all at this time. Thanks to Apple's private APIs all the computing, saving and loading have to be done in a parent iOS App.

That mean that you can't save/load anything from apple watch directly. You have to make request on the parent iOS App and the app should save/load everything you need to/from keychain and then return data to the Apple watch.

I hope Apple will public API for more native Apple watch apps as soon as possible.

Comment: Yep. You're completely right about that. That's too bad.